# Is the performance of CoreData with LIKE much worse than standard SQLite on IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am querying a very simple database of approximately 250,00 english words using NSFetchedResultsController. I construct the following predicate using [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubPredicates]:

```
"word LIKE '*a*' AND word LIKE '*b*' AND word LIKE '*c*' AND word LIKE '*d*'"
```

When I run the query by calling [NSFetchedResultController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:...] it takes about 8 seconds to run.

I can run the equivalent query on exactly the same database using sqlite3:

```
"Select word from words where word LIKE '%a%' AND word LIKE '%b%' ..."
```

and the cpu time is about .01 seconds.

Is the difference in the use of LIKE or in the use of NSPredicate or in NSFetchedResultsController?

UPDATE

At the moment, the object model is about as simple as it could be, consisting of a single *Word* object, with three properties
    NSString * word
    NSString * sortedWord
    NSInteger length.

Here's a screen grab from Instruments - Time Profiler (I'm not sure of a better way to share data from Instruments) which shows (I think) that the bulk of the time is being spend in  [ _NSPredicateUtiltiesDoRegexForString:Pattern:likeProtect:flags:Context:].

http://www.mckaydalton.com/images/instruments.jpg

In addition, here's the SQLDebug output:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZLENGTH, t0.ZSORTEDSTRING, t0.ZWORD FROM ZWORD t0 WHERE ( NSCoreDataLike( t0.ZWORD, ?, 0)  AND  NSCoreDataLike( t0.ZWORD, ?, 0) ) ORDER BY t0.ZWORD
```

CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 10.7353s

CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 10.7439s for 24891 rows.

Here the same select using "raw" sqlite3 acting on the same database:

```
SELECT 0, Z_PK, Z_OPT,ZSORTEDSTRING, ZWORD FROM ZWORD WHERE ZWORD LIKE '%a%' AND ZWORD LIKE '%b%' ORDER BY ZWORD;
```

CPU Time: user 0.377206 sys 0.054738

It would seem to me, therefore, that the NSCoreDataLike is behaving very differently from the "LIKE" built in to sqlite.  This is not a major issue as I can just use the C-api to sqlite (although  I would like to keep the project in CoreData as it gets bigger, if possible) or use CONTAINS instead of LIKE (although this will require changing the application logic), but it would be nice to understand what is going on

Comment: Why don't you fire up Instruments, run a few small tests, and let the tool answer your question.  You will get a much better answer, and you will learn something in the process.

Comment: Fair point, Jody.  Thanks.  Some initial results with Instruments and also using com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug to debug the actual SQL leads me to the answer that the problem lies with NSCoreDataLike.  This simple query `select word from words where word like '%a%' and word like '%b%' order by word` has a total fetch execution time of 10.57 seconds versus 0.38 seconds for direct SQL.  I was under the impression that, in general, CoreData performs at least as well as sqlite.  So my more specific question is:  Have I picked a particularly obtuse counter-example or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: If you look at the breakdown in instruments, you can see exactly **where** all the time is being spent.  Note, that you may be surprised, but Core Data does not pretend to be a pure relational database.  It is an object graph manager that happens to also persist the object graph.  Now, you can still get good performance from CD, but it does require some specific knowledge, especially when using stuff like `LIKE`.  Post the details of your core data model, the function you are using for the fetch, some Instruments results, and we'd be glad to help you interpret them.